# django-registration module dont send email

Tags: python, django, django-registration

I am trying to send activation email and reset email in Django. I am using Django registration module but after registration, the page returned back to the registration page and did not send any email to me.
Part of **settings.py** :

```
DEBUG = False

ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['mysite.com', 'www.mysite.com']

EMAIL_BACKEND ='django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend' 
DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL = 'info@mysite.com'
EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'info@mysite.com'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = 'my pass'
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True 
EMAIL_PORT = 1025

# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'posts',
    'registration',
    'django_countries',
    'crispy_forms',
    'django_forms_bootstrap',
    'captcha', 
   ]

ACCOUNT_ACTIVATION_DAYS = 7
REGISTRATION_AUTO_LOGIN = True
SITE_ID = 1
```

After clicking on the register button, browser waits for 2 seconds on this page.

[image]

Comment: Try some debugging. i.e. disable tls and run a ``netcat -lp 1025`` and see if there is some mail incoming. Maybe even checking your mailserver log will already show the problem. Or you will notice, that no mail is sent to the server/port and the configuration still has issues.

Comment: @allo i disable tls , my setting is EMAIL_BACKEND ='django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'
EMAIL_HOST = 'modmozel.ir'
EMAIL_PORT = 2096
DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL = 'info@modmozel.ir'
EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'info@modmozel.ir'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = 'mypass'
EMAIL_USE_TLS = False

Comment: and do you receive something, when listening on port 2096 with netcat or some other tcp-debugging tool? you should see something like "HELO myhostname" or "EHLO myhostname", when the mail is being sent to this port.

Comment: @allo see this Username:  info@modmozel.ir
Password:  Use the email account’s password.
Incoming Server:  mail.modmozel.ir

    IMAP Port: 143
    POP3 Port: 110

Outgoing Server:  mail.modmozel.ir

    SMTP Port: 25

Comment: Wwwwork....the problem was in my settings.py . imust founded the right email server and port i use EMAIL_HOST =  mail.modmozel.ir and EMAIL_PORT=25

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forget to add

```
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.mysite.com'
```

to send email.

Comment: i added but did not work. after click on register button loading 2 second on white page and turn back to registration page

Comment: I am using this, and it works for me well,
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.mysite.com'
EMAIL_USE_TLS=1
EMAIL_PORT=587
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = 'test'
EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'test'
SERVER_EMAIL = 'support@mysite.com'

try this once.

Answer (score 0):

if use cpanel you must first create a email account and then go to Set Up Mail Clien and in Non-SSL Settings section write the outgoing server and port in settings.py

```
 EMAIL_BACKEND ='django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'
EMAIL_HOST = 'outgoingserver'
EMAIL_PORT = SMTP_port
DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL = 'your email account'
EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'your email account'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = 'email password'
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
```